# python, plotly, raspberry pi - online streaming does not work

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, plotly

Hi for several years I was using plotly with online streaming feature.
Without any change of code it stopped to work because RPi was outdated (SSL).
Then I loaded new raspbian and plotly from python-plotly debian package.

What I can see now are several warnings about deprecated calls.

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/plotly/graph_objs/_deprecations.py:504: DeprecationWarning:                                                                                          

plotly.graph_objs.Stream is deprecated.                                                    
Please replace it with one of the following more specific types                            
  - plotly.graph_objs.scatter.Stream                                                       
  - plotly.graph_objs.area.Stream                                                          


/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/plotly/graph_objs/_deprecations.py:372: DeprecationWarning:

plotly.graph_objs.Line is deprecated.
Please replace it with one of the following more specific types
  - plotly.graph_objs.scatter.Line
  - plotly.graph_objs.layout.shape.Line
  - etc.


/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/plotly/graph_objs/_deprecations.py:531: DeprecationWarning:

plotly.graph_objs.XAxis is deprecated.
Please replace it with one of the following more specific types
  - plotly.graph_objs.layout.XAxis
  - plotly.graph_objs.layout.scene.XAxis


/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/plotly/graph_objs/_deprecations.py:558: DeprecationWarning:

plotly.graph_objs.YAxis is deprecated.
Please replace it with one of the following more specific types
  - plotly.graph_objs.layout.YAxis
  - plotly.graph_objs.layout.scene.YAxis


/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/plotly/graph_objs/_deprecations.py:39: DeprecationWarning:

plotly.graph_objs.Data is deprecated.
Please replace it with a list or tuple of instances of the following types
  - plotly.graph_objs.Scatter
  - plotly.graph_objs.Bar
  - plotly.graph_objs.Area
  - plotly.graph_objs.Histogram
  - etc.
```

I tried to resolve these warnings and also used the latest streaming examples, but the problem is same.

Code hangs here:

```
py.plot(fig, filename='My Plot')
```

after calling it is sitting there for unlimited time with unknown reason.
I dont know how to debug it or find why it is happening.

I tried also `py.iplot()` with the same result.

Can you help me please? How to make it work again. I am using Python 2.7.

Here is my source code:

```
    import plotly.plotly as py
    from plotly.graph_objs import Scatter, Layout, Figure, Data, Stream, XAxis, YAxis, Legend, Line

    while True:
        if plotly_running == 0:
            break
        else:
            time.sleep(1)
            print "Waiting for plotly thread to end.."

    with open('./config.json') as config_file:
        plotly_user_config = json.load(config_file)

    trace_a = Scatter(
        x=[],
        y=[],
        stream=Stream(
            token=plotly_user_config['plotly_streaming_tokens'][0],
            maxpoints=1000
        ),
        yaxis='y',
        name='A',
        line=Line(
            color="blue"
        ),
    )

    trace_b = Scatter(
        x=[],
        y=[],
        stream=Stream(
            token=plotly_user_config['plotly_streaming_tokens'][1],
            maxpoints=1000
        ),
        xaxis='x2',
        yaxis='y2',
        name='B',
        line=Line(
            color="rgb(212, 189, 74)"
        ),
    )

    trace_e = Scatter(
        x=[],
        y=[],
        stream=Stream(
            token=plotly_user_config['plotly_streaming_tokens'][4],
            maxpoints=1000
        ),
        yaxis='y',
        name='C',
        line=Line(
            color="green"
        ),
    )

    trace_c = Scatter(
        x=[],
        y=[],
        stream=Stream(
            token=plotly_user_config['plotly_streaming_tokens'][3],
            maxpoints=1000
        ),
        yaxis='y',
        name='D',
        line=Line(
            color="red"
        ),
    )

    trace_d = Scatter(
        x=[],
        y=[],
        stream=Stream(
            token=plotly_user_config['plotly_streaming_tokens'][2],
            maxpoints=1000
        ),
        xaxis='x2',
        yaxis='y2',
        name='F',
        line=Line(
            color="orange"
        ),
    )

    trace_f = Scatter(
        x=[],
        y=[],
        stream=Stream(
            token=plotly_user_config['plotly_streaming_tokens'][5],
            maxpoints=500
        ),
        xaxis='x2',
        yaxis='y2',
        name='G',
        line=Line(
            color="purple"
        ),
    )

    layout = Layout(
        title='My Plot Data',
        showlegend=True,
        width=600,
        height=600,
        autosize=True,

        xaxis=XAxis(
            anchor='y'
        ),
        xaxis2=XAxis(
            anchor='y2'
        ),
        yaxis=YAxis(
            title='Temp [C]',
            domain=[0.6, 1]
        ),
        yaxis2=YAxis(
            title='Common',
            range=[0, 100.0],
            domain=[0, 0.4]
        )
    )

    data = Data([trace_a, trace_b, trace_c, trace_d, trace_e, trace_f])
    fig = Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

    py.sign_in(plotly_user_config["plotly_username"], plotly_user_config["plotly_api_key"])

    print py.plot(fig, filename='My Plot')


    stream_a = py.Stream(plotly_user_config['plotly_streaming_tokens'][0])
    stream_a.open()

    stream_b = py.Stream(plotly_user_config['plotly_streaming_tokens'][1])
    stream_b.open()

    stream_c = py.Stream(plotly_user_config['plotly_streaming_tokens'][4])
    stream_c.open()

    stream_d = py.Stream(plotly_user_config['plotly_streaming_tokens'][3])
    stream_d.open()

    stream_e = py.Stream(plotly_user_config['plotly_streaming_tokens'][2])
    stream_e.open()

    stream_f = py.Stream(plotly_user_config['plotly_streaming_tokens'][5])
    stream_f.open()

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)

        # write the data to plotly
        try:
            stream_a.write({'x': datetime.datetime.now(), 'y': "%.2f" % a})
            stream_b.write({'x': datetime.datetime.now(), 'y': "%.2f" % b})
            stream_d.write({'x': datetime.datetime.now(), 'y': "%.2f" % c})
            stream_e.write({'x': datetime.datetime.now(), 'y': "%.3f" % d})
            stream_c.write({'x': datetime.datetime.now(), 'y': "%.2f" % e})
            stream_f.write({'x': datetime.datetime.now(), 'y': "%.2f" % f})
        except Exception, e:
            print "> Plotly - " + str(e)
```

Comment: Depricated means that the code used, will be removed in a future version, but for now still works. So the deprication warnings are probebly not the problem. Are there any error showing up? Can you edit your question and post your source code?

Comment: Source Code was added to the original post. No error is seen at all. Just hangs at the py.plot(fig, filename='My Plot') line.

Comment: Is there anyone with working streaming actually?